# How to use Java User Input Scanner with multiple loops

Tags: java, input

I am trying to create a program that prompts the user to enter a name (1 of three options x,y,or z) and a certain variable (that is less than 10). If both of these inputs are true it will print out the name and the number as : (" you choose x times 2")

I am stuck because I'm new to the java scanner class (and java) and don't know how to configure the code with if statements checking two factors.

Help?

My code so far: I know a lot of it wrong:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerAndKeyboard {

public static void main(String[] args)
{   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Welcome");
    System.out.print( "Enter your name: "  );
    String name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "Hello " + name + "!" );
    System.out.print("Please Enter letter and number: " ); 

    if(s.nextLine().equals(X) && s.nextInt() <= 10)
      System.out.println( "You choose x10");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample input please? Actually - give us a few example inputs, and the expected outputs. Your description is terrible. There are 3 people that don't understand you!

Comment: Inputs:  X 9, X 8, X 7,.... Y 9, Y 8, Y 7,...   Z 9, Z 8, Z 7,.....                                     the outputs would be: You choose X 9"                              The letter has to be X, Y, or Z and the number has to be less than ten.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerAndKeyboard {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome");
        System.out.print( "Enter your name: "  );
        String name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println( "Hello " + name + "!" );
        System.out.print("Please Enter letter and number: " ); 
        String X = s.useDelimiter("\\s").next();
        int num = s.nextInt();

        if((X.equalsIgnoreCase("x") || X.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ||
                X.equalsIgnoreCase("z")) && num < 10)
          System.out.println( "You choose "+X+num);
    }
}
```

I tested by verifying the following inputs (you can modify the prompts):

```
WelcomeEnter your name: Alvin
Hello Alvin!
Please Enter letter and number: X 9
You choose X9
```

Comment: I don't understand why you marked @Aashray answer as correct, because you said the numbers must be less than 10??? Mine checks that.

Answer (score -1):

From your code, I don't see a variable named `X`. So I'm assuming you want a character comparison.

`if(s.nextLine().equals("X") && s.nextInt() <= 10)`

Wrap `X` with double quotes and it should solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

If you need to add a variable and check for `x,y or z` then do the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerAndKeyboard {

public static void main(String[] args)
{   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Welcome");
    System.out.print( "Enter your name: "  );
    String name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "Hello " + name + "!" );
    System.out.print("Please Enter letter and number: " ); 
    String X = s.nextLine();
    if((X.equalsIgnoreCase("x") || X.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || X.equalsIgnoreCase("z")) && s.nextInt() <= 10)
      System.out.println( "You choose "+X+" 10");
}
}
```

**EDIT 2**

If they are to be in the same line, then do this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerAndKeyboard {

public static void main(String[] args)
{   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Welcome");
    System.out.print( "Enter your name: "  );
    String name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "Hello " + name + "!" );
    boolean stat = true;
    while(boolean)
    System.out.print("Please Enter letter and number: " ); 
    String X = s.nextLine();
    String[] X1 = X.split(" ");
    if((X1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("x") || X1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("y") || X1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("z")) && Integer.parseInt(X1[1]) <= 10)
      System.out.println( "You choose "+X1[0]+" "+X1[1]);
      stat = false;
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
}
}
```

Comment: I think I'm supposed to add a variable how would I set up the three possible letters x, y, and z? Sorry for the bad questions

Comment: After the adding the variable, what are you supposed to check it with?

Comment: i tied the program but it doesn't do anything when add the letter and number.

Comment: What do you mean "when add the letter and number"?

Comment: After I prompt them to "Enter letter and number" I want it to be entered in the form of "(letter) (number)" for example "x 9" then if the letter is one of the three and the number is less than 10 I want to print out "you choose x 10"           Thank You

Comment: Now check and let me know.

Comment: the program prompts you to input the letter and the number. When this is typed in nothing happens.

Comment: Are you giving a space in-between the letter and number?

Comment: yes, and how would you modify the program so that it returns that an input is invalid if it does not meet the criteria

Comment: Just add an `else` branch to the `if`.

Comment: and how would I make it loop back to the prompt to input letter and number if the input is invalid?       thank you for helping

Comment: Edited my code to match your requirements. If this the answer what you are looking for, upvote and accept as answer.

Comment: Go to the link I have pasted and see. It works fine.